# Android studio git commit for giberish

Tags: git, android-studio

I have opened a project which already had a git folder inside it. Whenever I commit from android studio I see this

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information?  Was this Git folder from some other project, which somehow ended up in there?  Or, is this just the Git folder for your actual current project?  What does `git status` from the bash show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The git folder is for this project, and when I do a git status from bash I get a normal response